Using materials for mkdocs, and generate PDF. The SVG rendering loses in PDF
On the website, SVG can be rendered normally,

but in pdf, css rendering loses.

Configurations in materials for mkdocs:
plugins:
  - with-pdf:
      cover_subtitle: test     
      cover: true
      back_cover: true
      copyright: Copyright &copy; Abby.huang -  All rights reserved.
      # cover_logo: 'https://cloud-cdn.nebula-graph.com.cn/nebula-for-pdf.png'
      output_path: pdf/abby.pdf

With-pdf uses weasyprint to generate pdf for materials for mkdocs.
And it seems like that WeasyPrint does not render CSS normally when CSS or HTML comming from untrusted users.
How can I solve it? Thanks in advance!
